# oidc-client with IdentityServer3 - Angular2 SPA, how to refresh data access token

Tags: angular, openid-connect, identityserver3

I'm using oidc-client.js with IdentityServer3.

I have everything working well at this point, except for renewing access tokens. I have an Angular2 SPA and I'm capturing the AccessTokenExpiring event and allowing the user to decide to continue working or logout. The logout was easy. However, i'm struggling with which userManager method to call to refresh my data access token. It seems if I use signInSilent(), I will need to provide a silent redirect uri, which I assume the Idsvr will redirect to, which I'd rather not have, as it would redirect from where the user is currently working. Is there a solid example of what I should be doing??

Thanks!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Renewing tokens in the implicit flow is done by redirecting the user via the front channel (IOW the browser). There's no approach for programmatically doing this for JS style clients.

Answer (score 0):

As I understand this, the `signInSilent` mechanism of the `UserManager` allows the the user to be authenticated in a hidden iframe.

The silent redirect uri should be where you process the token returned from IdentityServer.

Of course this can only work silently if the user is still logged in to IdentityServer at the moment the token expires.

If the user has been logged out of IdentityServer you can put some logic in your code (that gets triggered at your silent redirect uri) to detect this (IdentityServer will respond with an `error login_required`).
At which point you can trigger normal authentication here or using the `silentRenewError`event.

The application state can be saved during a roundtrip to IdentityServer by passing it to `UserManager.signinRedirect({data:'Your data here'}`).

You could also use `UserManager.signinPopup({data:'Your data here'}` to avoid navigating away from the application in the main window. Where `popup_redirect_uri` can be where you process the callback and trigger the event with the new user to update any UI in your main window.

[oidc-client.js Wiki](https://github.com/IdentityModel/oidc-client-js/wiki)

[Issue which covers signInSilent process](https://github.com/IdentityModel/oidc-client-js/issues/98)